# Invariants of Iwasawa modules

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, iwasawa-theory

Let $\Lambda$ denote Iwasawa algebra $\mathbb{Z}_p[[\Gamma]]$, where $\Gamma$ is a group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$(ring of $p$-adic integers). The structure theorem of the Iwasawa module says: If M is a finitely generated $\Lambda$-module, then

$$M \sim \Lambda^r \oplus \bigoplus_{i=1}^t \Lambda/p^{n_i} \oplus \bigoplus_{j=1}^s \Lambda/f_j^{m_j}$$
is a pseudo-isomorphism (maps with finite kernel and cokernel). If $M$ is $\Lambda$-torsion (i.e., $r=0$), then in most of the articles they define

- The $\mu$-invariant of $M$ is $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n n_i $.
- The characteristic ideal of $M$ is $p^{\mu(M)} \displaystyle \prod_j^s f_j^{m_j}\Lambda$.

Clearly, the definitions of both invariants are independent of $r$ (rank). My question is:

- why do we need the torsion condition to define them?

I understand that most of the objects that appear in theory are torsion, but what are the drawbacks if we define them for a non-torsion f.g. module?

Note: There is a similar thread [Pseudo-isomorphism in Iwasawa Theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3692286/pseudo-isomorphism-in-iwasawa-theory) for characteristic ideals, but the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3694083) is not convincing to me.
Is there something I'm missing in that post?

Comment: The characteristic ideal should be $p^{\mu(M)}\cdot \prod f_j^{m_j} \, \Lambda$.

Comment: You could extend the definition if it helps, but the extended notions won't satisfy the same nice properties. E.g, the characteristic ideal of torsion modules is multiplicative in short exact sequences, but not for $0\to \Lambda\to^f\Lambda\to \Lambda/f\Lambda\to 0$

Comment: For finitely generated $\Lambda$-modules, the invariants $r$, $n_i$, $f_j$ and $m_j$ are uniquely determined, so, yes, you can use them to define the extensions. However $\sim$ is not reflexive unless they are torsion as the inclusion of the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{M}\subset \Lambda$ shows.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understood that the modified definition is not helpful for f.g $\Lambda$-modules.